# how to sending POST request via curl

Tags: json, curl

i try to sending a query via curl as below,

```
curl -XGET 'X.X.X.X:9200/_all/record/_search? -d
"bool" : {
 "must" : [ {
  "term" : {
    "name" : "jar"
  }
}, {
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "keyword",
    "fields" : [ "message" ]
  }
} ],
"filter" : {
  "range" : {
    "@timestamp" : {
      "from" : "2016-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "to" : "2016-05-31T00:00:00.000Z",
      "include_lower" : true,
      "include_upper" : true
     }
   }
 }
}
}
```

I get a error

> curl: (3) [globbing] nested  brace in column 57

How can I PUT the query to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my POST with cURL:

```
@ECHO OFF



SET URL="http://......."
SET INPUT_FILE=%1_SetClienti_in.xml
SET OUTPUT_FILE=%1_SetClienti_out.xml
SET CURLEXE="curl.exe"

SET INPUT=%INPUT_FILE%
SET OUTPUT=%OUTPUT_FILE%

%CURLEXE%^
 --silent^
 --insecure^
 -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8;Accept: application/xml"^
  -d @%INPUT%^
 -X POST^
 %URL%^
 -o %OUTPUT%
```

It sends a xml file in input and get another one as output. Hope it helps.